# Cannot install PyQt4 to Python3 properly (Mac)

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qmake, qt-designer

I'm trying install PyQt4 so that I can implement a GUI I pieced together from Qt Designer and would like connect it to backend code I have developed in Python 3. I'm relatively new to Python and the various modes of installing and building are still confusing to me.

I've tried following this guide here: https://gist.github.com/guillaumevincent/10983814, and replacing PyQt5 with PyQt4, however when reaching this step "python3 configure.py --destdir ~/.env/ariane_mail/lib/python3.4/site-packages --qmake ~/Qt5.2.1/5.2.1/clang_64/bin/qmake" I have problems. I run this command whenever I am in the directory "/var/tmp/PyQt...4" exchanging 5.2.1 for the version I am running.

I realized however that clang_64 doesn't exist, well, because I don't have a /User/username/PyQt4 folder to begin with. Is there a step I am missing?

Also, someone mentioned in the comments to use "workon ariane_mail" before the long command I mentioned above. However I then receive "-bash: workon: command not found". Any tips why it's not found?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: [`workon`](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command_ref.html#controlling-the-active-environment) would be virtualenvwrapper's way of activating that virtualenv, you can just source `$venv/bin/activate` instead. The clang_64 directory should be where you installed the qt libraries to.

Comment: For PyQt4 you'd probably also need to use Qt4, which is unmaintained since December 2015. Why not use PyQt5?

Comment: By the way, I ended up using PyQt5, @TheCompiler . Make sense. Everything works now. Thanks all